# how to download static file in gatsby js

Tags: javascript, download, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I have a website with Gatsby.JS

I want to when click download button, download one static pdf file.

```
<button>
    <a download={`../../file.pdf`}> İndir</a>
</button>
```

this `../../file.pdf` is path of static folder.

Above code my downloadable code.

But this is not work. How can i fix.?

Answer (score 1):

The `download` attribute, summarizing a lot is just a way to set the name of the downloadable element but it's the `href` attribute the one that must point to the item you want to download.

This should work:

```
<a download={`Some Fancy Name`} href={`../../file.pdf`}>İndir</a>
```

Double-check the `../../file.pdf` path to ensure that is valid or that the `file.pdf` belongs to that route.

The static folder replicates its internal structure to the public (`/public`) one when the site builds. So, a structure like: `/static/file.pdf` should be pointed as:

```
<a download={`Some Fancy Name`} href={`/file.pdf`}>İndir</a>
```

Since the static folder becomes the "root", the level 0.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the issue